# Limit the products on the Virtuemart 2.0.18 Administrator Product Listing by vendor

Tags: php, e-commerce, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I was able to setup a webstore using virtuemart 2.0.18 and was able to create several users as vendors but I want to limit the display for this vendor for them to just see what products are assigned to them in the administrator product listing and would not able to see what other vendors are selling, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ive been working very little with VirtueMart so my information may be incorrect but have you tried creating different groups and assign those vendors and products to those groups?

Comment: I tried that already but it's still doing the same thing, it's really showing all products to all vendors whether they own the product or not.